# OOP Creational Design Pattern

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have the following data types and I'm struggling to implement a good design to create instances for different types.

Events: I have different type of events (`EventA`, `EventB` etc.)

- Each event might have subtypes. For example, `EventAA` and `EventAB` are subtypes of `EventA`,likewise `EventBA` and `EventBB` are subtypes of `EventB`.
- Each event has `source` and `output` but the types differ. For example `EventAA` has `List<String>` as source, `EventBB` has `int` as a source. Same thing with the output.

At the end, I need to create `EventAA`, `EventBA` with their source and outputs. I tried to apply Abstract Factory design pattern to create events, defined `Event`, `EventSource`, `EventOutput` as abstract class. Also, created `EventAFactory` and `EventBFactory` classes. Although, my sub events EventAA and EventAB has source and output, types may differ. Therefore, I couldn't generalize the `createEvent()` method. For each different type of inputs, I defined a `createEvent(type, source, output)` method but that doesn't feel right. Use cases for AbstractFactory design pattern online doesn't have subtypes like me (`EventAA` etc.) and I confused.

Comment: Why do you feel that you need to use a design pattern?

Comment: Use generics? `class Event<S, T>`; `class EventAA extends Event<List<String>, Integer>` Likewise, `createEvent` could be `<S, T> createEvent(Class<Event<S, T>> type, S source, T target)`

Comment: @azurefrog, Since the number of events might be increase, I feel that it is better to use some abstraction instead of using concrete class and new operator everytime.

Comment: If the number of events *might* increase, you should only add abstraction now if it will be faster to write that code now, rather than adding it later.  See [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).